# Is it possible to tell if user opened or downloaded a file?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dialog, download

I have a controller returning

```
return base.File(filepath, "application/pdf", "filename");
```

This creates a dialog for open/save.  Is it possible to detect whether the user chooses save or open?

Alternatively, if I return this:

```
return base.File(filepath, "filename");
```

It forces the user to download from a left-click.  If they right-click->Save File As, then they have the option to save. Is it possible to detect the difference between open and save here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Server does not receive any information from the client after request to get the file. You can confirm it with a HTTP watch utility like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Thanks, Fiddler looks like it might come in handy.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this method. This will tell you whether your file is in open state by another process or not

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        // file is used by another process
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
}
```

Comment: -1 - unrelated to the question. getit wants to detect if user opened file on its own machine after downloading from server (MVC). Your code may provide some information about local files only.

Comment: Thanks. But if we can find out user download location and then parse the absolute file path into a FileInfo and then send that fileinfo object to above method. Will it not work what he wants?

Comment: No, in ASP.Net/MVC case code runs on server, but file is opened on user's machine. There is no way from code on server to run something like you've suggested to check files on user's machine. It also not possible to run any code like this from browser due to security restrictions.